# Eclipse Neon2 repeatedly crashes when debugging PHP with XDebug

Tags: eclipse, crash, xdebug

I wanted to start PHP development and installed Apache, php 7.1 and xdebug with homebrew on my mac with OSX Sierra. Often (but not always), when I go to debug mode in Eclipse and step through my code, Eclipse stops working and crashes hard (program doesn't respond anymore).

Now I absolutely have no clue where I could start to analyze the error. Maybe it's an issue with Eclipse and XDebug?

Any idea where where to start and where I could find some helpful information (logs etc.)?

Comment: The main Eclipse log is the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory. (Note: these are hidden directories and files on macOS so won't see them in Finder.)

Comment: Good to know, but unfortunately there is no helpful information inside the logs. Seems that those crashes are not logged inside of eclipse :(

Comment: I have the exact same Problem. I checked the .log-File but there is no entry from the time of the Crash.